# How to comapre two list of hibernate entities are equal

Tags: java, list, hibernate, jpa, java-8

I have list of 2 hibernate entities.
 I need to compare them. When I use `equals()` it always gives false as its reference is different.

```
E1.equals(E2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're taking a reference to the `List` object only when evaluating equality. You would have to iterate through the collections to check (assuming the ordering is important):

```
E1.size() == E2.size() && IntStream.range(0, E1.size())
    .allMatch(index -> E1.get(index).equals(E2.get(index)));
```

P.S.1: Variable names are written lowercase in java.

P.S.2: Make sure you're defining `equals` and `hashCode` properly. By default same entity is not equal in different states (managed, detached).